# Access an item in map by two-item array key

Tags: javascript

I create a simple map:

```
const myMap = new Map([[[3,6], 'hello']]);
```

Where the key is a two-item array.
If I try to access it like so:

```
console.log(myMap.get([3,6]))
```

I will get `undefined`. However if I get the keys of that map:

```
const keyArray = [...myMap.keys()];
console.log(myMap.get(keyArray[0])) // hello
```

I will be able to access that key. This is even though `keyArray[0]` is just an array of `[3,6]`.
Is it related to something in its prototype? What makes it different than just trying to access the map with a new array of `[3,6]`? And then what would be a practical way to access such key easily and hopefully dynamically?

Comment: Because `[1] == [1]` would be false already ...? Arrays do not compare like that in JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe, That's true. As far as I understand, you must access the same array you used in the key when created the map

Comment: Yes, it needs to be the same _instance_, and not just a different array that happens to contain the same elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because every time you use [3,6] it create new array that has a different reference from the previous one so no [3, 6] are a like you can check that by logging this statement:

```
console.log([3,6] === [3,6]) // this log false always
```

to solve your issue you can save the array inside another variable to save the reference then use this variable to access the value inside your `Map`.

you can try this in you code

```
const myArray = [3,6]
const myMap = new Map([[myArray, 'hello']]);
console.log(myMap.get(myArray)) // this output 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

Keys are compared either by value for primitive types or by reference for Objects.
When you use an array as the key, you won't get a hit unless you use the original array as the key.

```
const myMap1 = new Map([[[3,6], 'hello']]);
console.log(myMap1.get([3,6])); // undefined

const a = [3,6];
const myMap2 = new Map([[a, 'hello']]);
console.log(myMap2.get(a)); // hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same instance as a key, like this:

```js
const key = [3, 6]
const myMap = new Map([[key, 'hello']])
console.log(myMap.get(key)) // hello
```

Also this is not right that

> keyArray[0] is just an array of [3,6]

`keyArray[0]` is the very array you give as a key, because `Map.prototype.keys()` returns a new Iterator object that contains the keys for each element in the Map object.

And because your map keys are arrays they are not copied, cause spread operator makes here a shallow copy of keys (only links for arrays).

```js
const keyArray = [...myMap.keys()];
console.log(key === keyArray[0]); // true
console.log([3,6] === keyArray[0]); // false
console.log(myMap.get(keyArray[0])) // hello
```